# My normal user file system only works in read-only mode and i don't have the password for the root user

Tags: mount, permissions, filesystem, root, dmesg

I have Ubuntu Server V14.10.the administration of this system disappears with a former employee. I do not have the root password and apparently the file system for the user that I use is protected and will not let me modify any files..

there any way to remount the file system from a normal user or necessarily have to recover root ??

I've been reading about the issue and apparently the errors that appear with the `dmesg | grep "EXT4-fs error"` deal with the problem of the file system in read-only mode.

```
tacacs@Tacacs:/$ dmesg | grep "EXT4-fs error"
[49087.944165] EXT4-fs error (device dm-0): ext4_journal_check_start:56: Detected aborted journal
[49147.984664] EXT4-fs error (device dm-0): ext4_journal_check_start:56: Detected aborted journal
[272027.360154] EXT4-fs error (device dm-0): ext4_find_entry:1312: inode #6946817: comm sshd: reading directory lbl
[272627.768280] EXT4-fs error (device dm-0): ext4_find_entry:1312: inode #5768225: comm sshd: reading directory lbl
```

I would appreciate your help, I am a rookie in Linux

Comment: If you have physical access to the machine, you could create a LiveUSB and use that to back files up to a backup drive. I recommend you do this and then reinstall a supported version of Ubuntu.

Comment: ohh da "# $ excuse my ignorance, then the version that I have not quite right ?? = (

Comment: 14.10 is no longer supported, so we can't really help you with it. 15.10 is the current latest.

Answer (score 0):

hehe my specialty ;) computer security is a hobby of mine... when you start up the computer you will get a grub screen that displays the normal bootup option and below that "Advanced options for ubuntu" select that and go to one of the recovery terminals... *reboots my computer*... select the 2nd one in that menu it'll say "ubuntu with generic (recovery mode)" and some numbers mixed in there and it should give you an option interface with one that says root which will give you a full admin command prompt... I trust you know what you can do from there... (hint: passwd, nano /etc/group)

Comment: Hey wagyourtail. thanks for answering. So what you propose will try me and be back to tell you my experience. Thank you very much